# Real quadratic form signature

Tags: quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

The question goes as follows:

> Let $V = \mathbb R^{2n}$ be a vector space, and $q:V\to \mathbb R$ a real quadratic form. Let $\xi \in T_2^{sym}(V)$ be a bilinear functional for which $q(v) = \xi (v,v)$. Let us assume that $\xi$ is nondegenerate.
>
> Prove that $q$ has a signature $0$ iff there exists a basis $[e]$ such that $$q(v) =\sum_{i=0}^n x_iy_i$$ where $[v]^{[e]} = (x_1,y_1,...x_n,y_n)$.

I couldn't figure how to prove any of the directions of the "iff". This were my thoughts:

Since $q(v) = \xi (v,v)$, we get that $\xi$ is the polarization of $q$, and since $\xi$ is nondegenerate we get that the rank of $q$ must be $2n$, or equaly $n_{-} + n_{+} = 2n$.

Now, for the first direction we assume that the signature is $0$, therefore $n_- = n_+ = n$, but I don't know how to continue from there.

For the second direction, we get that in the basis $[e]$ we have the matrix representing $q$ as having $\frac{1}{2}$ on every even entry above and below the main diagonal (and all the rest are $0$s), but I don't know how to continue from here as well.

Would appreciate your help on this question, preferably hints to the direction and comments on my approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is less to this than may appear. All that is going on is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
- \frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & - \frac{1}{2} \\
1 &  \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 0 \\
0 & - \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If you really want diagonal entries $1,-1$ you can then multiply on left and right by
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & 0 \\
 &  \sqrt 2
\end{array}
\right),
$$
this matrix being its own transpose.

Other direction, you can construct a matrix $P$ of nonzero determinant such that 
$$ P^T C P = F,   $$
where we are given
$$
C =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & 0 \\
0 & - b
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with real $a,b > 0,$ while
$$
F =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$